# How does a servlet handle more bytes than available RAM?

Tags: java, performance, servlets, jvm

Lets say that I have a servlet running that accepts files of any size from a client application(s). The file being sent is loaded into a DataHandler and is transmitted by web-services; as such is received and put back into a DataHandler. What happens if the file being sent exceeds the size of available RAM on the receiving host?

My initial thoughts are:

1)The `JVM` will just put this in the virtual memory, as the size of the file would already been known through the header messages and the `JVM` could be sneaky and allocate the space ahead of time. However, I did not think that the virtual memory space could get to big.

2)The `JVM` will create a "hidden" file to hold all the data on the hard disk and then the `DataHandlers` output stream will just load the data back into the RAM as needed.

In either case it seems like it would be easier to just write the file to the hard disk anyway but I would like to avoid this as I will be using the data immediately after I receive it. The server hosting the `servlet` will have many different clients all sending large files around the same time and I am wondering how the `JVM` will handle issues like this.

Comment: It just streams the output?

Comment: A stream will not be written to disk since that would break the sandbox security, unless you define a location to write the file by using a writer (any).

Comment: So how does the JVM handle all of this data then, I assume it just gets placed in pages of virtual memory?

Comment: Think of streaming as the way a hose handles all the water passing through it. It doesn't need to hold all the water at any one time. The code which generates the XML or JSON (as per your question) writes it 'on the fly' to the stream. The whole "file" doesn't necessarily exist in one continuous piece (unless it's small enough to fit in the output buffer - but this is irrelevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet api provides streams on the request and response. The input stream on the request will only load bytes into the JVM as required.

The stream does not hold all the data in memory, a call to read() eventually gets some data out of a small buffer or causes a blocking read on a socket. An application could try to read the whole, large, stream into a byte array or other data structure, then you could run out of memory.

You could have a poke around in the code of an application server like tomcat or jetty to see how they interact with the socket. Here's one [from tomcat](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11InputBuffer.java).